# Converting $x^2 + 6y - 9 = 0$ to polar

Tags: polar-coordinates

Hi I'm trying to solve this problem but am having difficulty removing the remaining r. I have tried [in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thu1H.jpg)  but cannot get an answer.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: So WolframAlpha gives us the polar form $-(r \sin(\theta)-r-3) (r \sin(\theta)+r-3) = 0$. Did you want something more specific? See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%5E2*cos%28theta%29%5E2%2b6r*sin%28theta%29-9=0

Comment: Maybe you could isolate $y$, recognize equation of a conic (a parabola), and write its representation in polar coordinates (with focus not necessarily at O, by the way) ?

Answer (score 2):

As wrote Patrick Da Silva,
$$y = -\frac{1}{6} x^2 + \frac{3}{2}. \tag{*}$$
Put $$\begin {gather}
x=\rho \cos{\varphi}, \\
y-\frac{3}{2}=\rho \sin{\varphi},
\end{gather}$$
translating pole to the point $\left(0, \,\frac{3}{2}\right).$
Then $(*)$ becomes
$$\rho \sin{\varphi}=\rho^2 \cos^2{\varphi},$$
or, for $\rho\ne{0}$
$$\sin{\varphi}=\rho \cos^2{\varphi}.$$

Comment: @Brady Trainor Thanks, it's a typo

Comment: You're not exactly switching to polar because you don't center at $(0,0)$, but this does work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your curve is a polynomial. You can look at it this way. 
$$
y = -\frac 16 x^2 + \frac 32.
$$
If you want to switch into polar coordinates, it'll give you the same equation, in polar coordinates. You can't expect to "find $x$ and $y$" or to "find the value of $r$ and $\theta$". Are you asked to do something in particular?

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for the answer. I'm looking to find the steps to go from rectangular to polar. As highlighted in my work I'm trying to get it into and "r=" form  but cant see how to get it there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Direct translation gives $r^2\cos^2\theta +6r\sin\theta-9=0$. If we use one of the common conventions, that $r\ge 0$, we can solve explicitly for $r$ using the Quadratic Formula, getting
$$r=-3\cos\theta+3\sqrt{\sin^2\theta +1}.$$
But the second form is perhaps less attractive than the first implicit form.

There are various other ways to manipulate, for example by rewriting $\cos^2\theta$ as $1-\sin^2\theta$. All the answers we get by correct manipulations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to find a function $r(\theta)$ for the curve.

After substituting for $x$ and $y$, we should anticipate solving a quadratic formula. This is why you are having trouble solving for $r$. Try solving for $x$ in a general quadratic equation, and you will be faced with a similar obstruction.

$$r^2\cos^2\theta+6r\sin\theta-9=0.$$

We now apply the quadratic formula:

\begin{align*}
r&={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over 2a}\\
&={-6\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{36\sin^2\theta+36\cos^2\theta}\over 2\cos^2\theta}\\
&={-3\sin\theta\pm3\over \cos^2\theta}.
\end{align*}
Some care will be needed in choosing which of $\pm$ are chosen.

Comment: I think both choices will work. We can use Andres idea to choose $r\ge0$ by convention, so $r(\theta)=3(1-\sin\theta)/\cos^2\theta$.